# Laravel 8 redirect from old URL to New URL

Tags: php, laravel, seo, laravel-8

i'm planning to change all my website URls .. i made controller and model to save all old and new url in my DB

and add this in my web.php

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Redirections'],function(){
    $redirections=App\Models\Redirections::all();
    foreach($redirections as $r){
    Route::redirect($r->from,$r->to,$r->type, 301);
    }
});
```

my project link is https://www.website.com/new-laravel

old link https://www.website.com/new-laravel/old

new link https://www.website.com/new-laravel/old

my problem redirect send me to https://www.website.com/old

How i can fix this problem

Comment: So are you just putting `new-laravel` after your domain root? The `old` and `new` links in your question are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think putting your redirects into a database table is the best approach. You're going to have the overhead of a database call for each redirect vs just defining your redirects in the `web.php` route file.

If your redirects are as straight forward as your question is suggesting, adding `new-laravel` after your domain root, you could do the following in your `web.php` route file.

```
// catch all routes that don't contain 'new-laravel'
Route::any('{all}', function (Request $request) {
    return redirect(url('/new-laravel/' . $request->path()), 301);
})->where('all', '^((?!new-laravel).)*$');

// create a route group to wrap and catch all your old routes
Route::group('/new-laravel', function () {
  Route::get('/old', function () {
    ...
  });
});
```

So trying to access `website.com/old` will redirect to `website.com/new-laravel/old` without the overhead of a database call.

Comment: i have alote of urls need to be redirects and all not same that is why i have to do this ... can you suggest any other idea for my case?

Comment: @AhmedSaad You don't **have** to put the redirects in the database. Sometimes there just simply isn't an _easy_ solution.